# What property returns a string's value from a string object (for binding)?

Tags: wpf, converters

I have a converter that takes a string as input and returns an icon. It's used to provide a icon that is used in a list box. When the itemsSource is set to a list whose items have a property that returns a string, the XAML looks as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding FileName, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToIconConverter}}"/>
```

That is, the objects in the list have a property called FileName that is of type string.

However, I have another listbox whose itemsSource is a List. In this case, what property can be used to retrieve the string value of the List to send to the converter?

```
<Image Source="{Binding ??, Converter={StaticResource FileNameToIconConverter}}"/>
```

Thanks, Ted

Comment: Sounds like you want to bind to the selected item.
check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx), should help you

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I follow your question, but it sounds as though you're binding to a list of `string`s and you want to bind directly to the string rather than a property on the `string` class itself? In that case, don't specify a path, or specify "." as the path:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FileNameToIconConverter}}"/>
```

OR

```
<Image Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource FileNameToIconConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Kent. Yes, your understanding of my question is correct. Specifying "." as the path did the trick.